# Laravel Adding ? to E-mail

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4 to send an email to a mobile phone email address and it adds a ? to the beginning of the message. Sending as html or text makes no difference. I've tested using native PHP mail function as well as CodeIgniter's mail function to the same mobile email address and there is NO question mark. This is only happening when sending to a mobile email. Any suggestions?

```
public function send(){
        $data['name']= 'Jane';
        Mail::send(array('text' => 'textmessages.reminder'), $data, function($message){
            $message->from('me@myemail.com', 'Me');
            $message->to('1231231212@yourmobileemail.com')->subject('Test');
        });
    }
```

and the entire view:

```
Hi <?=$name?>
```

The text message reads:

> (Test) ?Hi Jane

Comment: are you using a blade template for the view?  Can you post more of the view?

Comment: Also, if it's a Blade view, can you do `{{{ $name }}}` instead?

Comment: That is the whole view. I did also try a blade view but same result using {{{ $name }}}.

Comment: Where is this `(Test)` coming from in your text message?

Comment: The question mark is coming from somewhere inside your code. I've used the emailer for laravel and have had no issues with question marks in odd places. Triple check every part of your code to make sure your not passing in anything odd.

Comment: I'm actually showing all of the code. There is nothing else to show. And this only shows up when I send to a mobile email using Laravel, but not to the same mobile email using Codeigniter or even native PHP mail function in Laravel.

Comment: Try with no variables. Static message, "Hello".

Comment: If you have the same issue with no variables, I suggest removing the vars from your post then so we can rule that out. Perhaps there's a non-printable character?

Comment: Same result after removing vars.

Comment: Now try hardcoding the message into the method instead of loading a view file. Then try an empty message. Also try a different mobile address. Just trying to help you debug, you gotta try different things.

Comment: just a long guess, i dont know how laravel works: why you are declaring `$data['name']` but you pass `$data` ? maybe you need to pass `$data['name']` ?

Comment: Ensure all your files are encoded in UTF-8. I am not familiar with Laravel, but ensure the mail module is in UTF-8 mode too, if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When view file was created, it was set to "Include Unicode Signature (BOM)" which was causing the problem (but only when sent to a mobile email address). Creating a new view file without this option checked solved the problem. No more question mark.

Comment: Try loading a different view file. Did you try that? There might have been a BOM or other unprintable character in your original one. This is not a solution or explanation.